# Can we calculate the sides of a right triangle knowing only its three angles and the sides of a similar triangle?

Tags: geometry

This is what I have been wondering for a few hours now. Is it possible to determine the sides of a right triangle knowing only its three inner angles and the sides of another, similar triangle (which also happens to be a right triangle. They basically are the same triangles but the second one is smaller in size).

[Here's a drawing I made in paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCsbP.png)

If we know the sides and angles of the red triangle, and knowing the black one is similar to it with equal angles, can we determine the sides of the black one?

Comment: Not unless you know the ratio making them similar. Maybe we have a $3-4-5$ triangle, or $6-8-10$, or $300-400-500$. All of these triangles are similar and will have the same angles, but without more information you can't ascertain anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can apply an arbitrary scaling transformation to a triangle. Doing so will preserve similarity and all angles, but change lengths. Which means that you can't determine lengths if all you have is angles and similarity.

You need *some* information on the lengths. It could be a single length of the triangle you're interested in. It could be a length ratio between the two similar triangles. It could be some external figure from which that ratio might be concluded. But without any additional data you don't have enough information.